# Problem in understanding natural isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I know what's natural isomorphism in linear algebra.But I failed to find an example of natural isomorphism in R^n to its dual space.Please give me an example.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of natural isomorphism you know? Because there is not (in the most common definition) a natural isomorphism from a vector space to its dual.

Comment: There is a natural isomorphism between the original and the double dual, but not the dual itself.  See, for example, the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space)

Comment: *"I know what's natural isomorphism":* that's surprising, since it's rare to find a clear definition (outside of category theory).  Can you tell us what your definition of a natural isomorphism is in linear algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Fix a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $\langle \, , \, \rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for instance the standard scalar product. Then define $$\phi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n*}, \quad x \mapsto \langle x, \, \cdot \, \rangle$$

Comment: This is an isomorphism with the dual, but it's not what would typically be called a "natural isomorphism".

Comment: It is "natural" in the sense that the definition is coordinate-free. Of course, it depends on the bilinear form you choose, but this is the way in which things work.

Comment: It is only coordinate-free because you have replaced the choice of a basis with the choice of a form.

Comment: Of course you must put some additional structure. From the point of view of projective duality, you are fixing a non-degenerate conic.

Comment: Anyway, one you fix a scalar product the isomorphism $V \to V^*$ is often called *natural*, whereas this never happens if you just fix a basis. In fact one of the usual ways in which Riesz Representation Theorem is stated in literature is *There is a natural isomorphism between a Hilbert space and its dual*, see for instance  Bogachev, Measure Theory 1, page  256.

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=there+is+a+natural+isomorphism+between+a+hilbert+space+and+its+dual&source=bl&ots=lTEunuCajd&sig=rXk8O-xl2A-PSrVkjH8Bw1iOWCA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi677n0-u_VAhVpAcAKHeGhD0A4ChDoAQhCMAU#v=onepage&q=there%20is%20a%20natural%20isomorphism%20between%20a%20hilbert%20space%20and%20its%20dual&f=false